# ¿Cómo hago para organizar las palabras de una frase, dadas la posición de cada palabra en una lista?

Tags: lista, string, datos, ordenar, position

Me dan dos listas, una con palabras y la otra con la posición en la que va la palabra, y me piden que retorne un *STR* organizando las palabras según la posición de la 2 lista.

De verdad he intentado de muchas formas y distintos ciclos, pero no soy capaz.

Comment: Ya que comentas que has intentado muchas formas y ciclos no estaría de más que colocaras el código de dichos intentos así la comunidad ve que tienes algún avance y se te guía para corregir los errores que puedas estar presentando. Te invito a leer, el [tour], [ask] y muy importante [repro]

Comment: Además de mostrar un [repro] de lo que has intentado, coloca la etiqueta del lenguaje que corresponde a tu pregunta.